# How to use background-images with SCSS + Parcel.js

Tags: javascript, sass, parceljs

I'm trying to use `parcel.js` and SCSS to use a background-image, but getting:

> ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 7d6454d814b6ce2e1592d3937c337ef3.js:1***

Or at times getting:

> Cannot read property 'js' of null

Here is my scss:

```
.hero{
  background-image: url('../../images/2ndpaper.jpg');
}
```

Here is my js:

```
import "../styles/index.scss";
import paperbg from "../images/2ndpaper.jpg";
```

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "development",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CB PC - Web Development",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --out-dir prod"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "client",
    "website"
  ],
  "author": "Designs by Harp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-4-grid": "^2.4.1",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "jshint": "^2.10.1",
    "sass": "^1.17.2"
  }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add new npm script try adding "--public-url ./" as they suggest in [Parcel documentation](https://parceljs.org/cli.html)

```
"build2": "parcel build src/index.html --public-url prod"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is late answer but the background image with Parcel.js and SCSS needs to be used in the way

```
background-image: image-set(url("path/to/image"));
```

This worked for me...

same answer for this question [Parcel JS - not wrapping background-image url in single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095147/parcel-js-not-wrapping-background-image-url-in-single-quotes)