# Parcel JS - not wrapping background-image url in single quotes

Tags: sass, parceljs

I'm using Parcel JS to do some simple SCSS compilation. On the Parcel live server everything looks fine, but when running the build command (in my case `parcel build index.html --public-url ./`) my background-images from the SCSS file are broken.

It seems as though even though the image is in single quotes e.g. `background-image: url('images/image.jpg');`, these are being removed on build and causing Chrome to think the image is an invalid property.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not receiving an answer I think I've managed to solve the problem. This seems to be one of two issues.

1. Out of date version of SASS (just a simple npm update)
2. It not liking files with spaces in - simply rename any times.